# Redirect page within site

Tags: php, html, web

My problem: Say someone wants to go to my site, which currently just shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9qIO.png. What I want is to redirect the root (www.anter-gerang.org) to a file on the server, such as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdunT.png, which is www.anter-gerang.org/1.php.
How do I redirect the site so that someone that goes to anter-gerang.org instead sees the 1.php file?

Comment: You could rename/copy your `1.php` file to `index.php` and that *should* work

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Still showing the "domain purchased" page.

Comment: Works for me now, you may have to clear your cache or perform a hard page refresh.

Comment: Could be you need to rename to index.HTML, depending on your settings in your .htaccess page.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways

1. Using `.htaccess` to  301 redirect
2. Html redirect
3. Js redirect

**301 redirect**

Create a `.htaccess` file **in the root directory** and perform a redirect where  anyone who goes to `example.com` will be redirected to `example.com/index.php`. Just replace your info.

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
        RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

> What does this code above do? Let's have a look at Example 1 -
>   Redirect example.com to www.example.com. The first line starts the
>   rewrite module. The next line:
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ specifies that the next
>   rule only fires when the http host (that means the domain of the
>   queried url) is not (- specified with the "!") www.example.com. The $
>   means that the host ends with www.example.com - and the result is that
>   all pages from example.com will trigger the following rewrite rule.
>   Combined with the inversive "!" is the result every host that is not
>   www.example.com will be redirected to this domain.
>
> The [NC] specifies that the http host is case insensitive. The escapes
>   the "." - because this is a special character (normally, the dot (.)
>   means that one character is unspecified).
>
> The final line describes the action that should be executed:
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]. The ^(.*)$ is
>   a little magic trick. Remember the meaning of the dot? If not, this
>   can be any character(but only one). The .* means that you can have a
>   lot of characters, not only one. This is what was intended. ^(.*)$
>   contains the requested url, without the domain. The next part
>   http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] describes the target of the
>   rewrite rule -this is the "final" used domain name, where $1 contains
>   the content of the (.*).
>
> The next part is also important, since it does the 301 redirect for us
>   automatically: [L,R=301]. L means this is the last rule in this run.
>   After this rewrite the webserver will return a result. The R=301 means
>   that the webserver returns a 301 moved permanently to the requesting
>   browser or search engine.

**Html redirect**

Although this solution and the **JS**, would require you to have an `.html` page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com'" />
```

> The content attribute is the delay before the browser redirects to the
>   new page, so here we've set it to 0 seconds. Notice that we don't need
>   to set a HTTP status code, but it's important to double check the
>   weird opening and closing of the quotes above (there are quotes within
>   quotes, so they need to be different types and matching).
>
> Although this method is the easiest way to redirect to a web page
>   there are a few disadvantages. According to the W3C there are some
>   browsers that freak out with the Meta refresh tag. Users might see a
>   flash as page A is loaded before being redirected to page B. It also
>   disables the back button on older browsers. It's not an ideal
>   solution, and it's discouraged to use at all.

**Js redirect**

In your `html` file add:

```
<script>
   window.location = "http://example.com/your_resource";
</script>
```

Comment: The last two requires that the page be loaded in order to work, and I'm trying to get the page to load by default, so only the htaccess is viable. either way, it did not work. Thanks for trying. :L

Comment: Then why not use 301 redirect ? why did it not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason, renaming 1.php to index.php didn't work, so I copied the contents of 1 and pasted it into index, which worked.
Thanks to everyone who answered, as they helped greatly (The answer was a combination of both)